# How to highlight player and speed coil in boblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

Me and someone are working on a game in boblox studio and we want to know how to highlight both the player and speed coil when it is equipped. Can someone help me with this?

We looked up code online but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

```js
local tool=script.Parent
local char=tool.Parent;char=char:IsA"Model"and char or char.Parent.Character
local v=Instance.new("SelectionBox",char)
v.Visible=false
v.Adornee=char
tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    v.Visible=true
end)
tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    v.Visible=false
end)
```

Comment: Wouldn’t a Highlight be better than a selectionbox?